# AWS lambda transformation to firehose using Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to transform data from a kinesis data stream using firehose and lambda but encounter the following error:

**Lambda.FunctionError,"Invalid output structure. Check your function and make sure the output is in required format. In addition to that, make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed.****

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []

    for record in event['records']:

        client = boto3.client('kinesis')
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(payload)

        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8') + b'\n').decode('utf-8')
        }
       output.append(output_record)
    print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))

    return {'records': output}
```